# How to make a custom directive with input field in angular-2?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am learning Angular-2 and experimenting on it. I was trying to build an angular-2 directive with an input field. Lets describe, I have a custom directive called `custom.directive.ts`:

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[inputDir]',    
})

export class InputDirective{}
```

Now I add here an input field, which I would like to use in my app.component.ts.

How may I do it?

Comment: Your Query does not describe what exactly you wanted to achieve from custom directive. Please click [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465542/angular2-input-field-to-accept-only-numbers) for one of the example to demostrate the use of directive.

Answer (score -3):

You can declare like this

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
  private _defaultColor = 'red';

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) { }

  @Input('myHighlight') highlightColor: string;

  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    this.highlight(this.highlightColor || this._defaultColor);
  }
  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    this.highlight(null);
  }

  private highlight(color: string) {
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'backgroundColor', color);
  }
}
```

and you can use this as attribute in any element like this.

```
<p [myHighlight]="color">Highlight me!</p>
```

Please do refer this link for details explanation

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html